# SQLite equal count value as condition

Tags: sqlite, count, division

I'm currently working on an SQLite query that has to retrun to me all players that are capable of fulfilling every role in the game. I currently have this code:

```
SELECT pr.name 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.name name, c.role role
            FROM players p, playerchampions pc, champions c 
                WHERE (p.name = pc.playername) & (pc.championname = c.name)) pr
                    WHERE COUNT(pr.name) = COUNT(DISTINCT pr.role)
```

The idea is that i just check if the player can fulfill the same amount of roles as there are distinct roles in the game, but i get a misuse of aggregate function COUNT() error. How should i handle this?

Answer (score 1):

This query could be written like this:

```
SELECT players.name
FROM players
JOIN playerchampions ON players.name = playerchampions.playername
GROUP BY players.name
HAVING COUNT(playerchampions.championname) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT role)
                                              FROM champions)
```